# How to store specific data in particular shard and the rest of the data in other shards in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding

We are implementing the tag aware sharding.

Here are the requirements:

```
//Add tags to shards 
sh.addShardTag("shard1", "range1"); 
sh.addShardTag("shard2", "range2"); 
sh.addShardTag("shard3", "range3");




//Add ranges to chunks 
sh.addTagRange("test.foo", {_id:MinKey}, {_id:MaxKey}, "range1"); 
sh.addTagRange("test.foo",  {_id:MinKey}, {_id:MaxKey}, "range2"); 
sh.addTagRange("test.foo",  {_id:50},  {_id:50}, "range3");
```

Everything works fine except range3 which gets ignored.

Need a way where in all the data gets stored in `shard1` or `shard2` except `{_id: 50}` which should get into `shard3`.

Also, `shard3` should only have data specific to `{_id: 50}`.